# Using results of subquery more times in one statement

Tags: mysql, variables, subquery

like the title, I would like to store the value of a subquery from a where clause in the variable or a select statment.

I got this statement which works fine:

```
SELECT a.ticket_id, (SELECT count(*) FROM im_data b WHERE a.ticket_id=b.ticket_id) as count FROM incidents a WHERE 7 < (SELECT count(*) FROM im_data b WHERE a.ticket_id=b.ticket_id);
```

In two statements:

```
SET @post =1;
SELECT a.ticket_id,@post FROM incidents a WHERE 5 < @post := (SELECT count(*) FROM im_data b WHERE a.ticket_id=b.ticket_id);
```

or with would possible with a join of course:

```
SELECT a.ticket_id,count(b.ticket_id) as count FROM incidents a JOIN im_data b ON a.ticket_id=b.ticket_id group by a.ticket_id having count(b.ticket_id) > 5
```

The problem is just I would like to know if it is possible to do the same with only one query. 
I tried to do it in many way which don't work with mysql:

```
SELECT a.ticket_id, (SELECT count(*) FROM im_data b WHERE a.ticket_id=b.ticket_id) as count FROM incidents a WHERE 7 < count

SELECT a.ticket_id, count FROM incidents a WHERE 7 < (SELECT count(*) FROM im_data b WHERE a.ticket_id=b.ticket_id) as count;

SELECT a.ticket_id, count FROM incidents a WHERE 7 < @a (SET @a = (SELECT count(*) FROM im_data b WHERE a.ticket_id=b.ticket_id);
```

As you maybe regonize it is not about to finish the task, it is about to get know if it is possible to store a subquery in a variable or in an alias to use it in the same statement a second time without having more then one statement or is there any other way to use value more then one time in a statement.

Greetz thentt

Comment: You may use temporary table for the subresults. Or You can use *inline views* to create "temporary table" on the fly - see https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/mysql/w/wiki/6347.inline-views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself while reseach for a question on stackoverflow ;-).

```
join (select @post := 1)
```

does the trick.

```
SELECT a.ticket_id,@post FROM incidents a JOIN (SELECT @post := 1)  b WHERE 5 < @post := (SELECT count(*) FROM im_data b WHERE a.ticket_id=b.ticket_id);
```